# How to serve static files in Spring Boot after uploading with Docker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, static

I dockerized my app and this controller perfectly saves my images locally on the disk.

My controller: Images save perfectly in **root directory**

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/image")
public class ImageController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        // if file already exists will do nothing
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(file.toURI());
    }
}
```

Inside my docker container:

```
root@server:/APP/spring-app# docker exec -it 5e4 sh
# ls
c7fb1b0b-41f8-4265-a388-d0b5e09e563f.Снимок.JPG spring.jar
# ^C
#
```

[inside docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaban.png)

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/");
    }
}
```

But when i try to get this image by link (https://api.*****.ru/img/c7fb1b0b-41f8...23432.JPG) i see this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 28 09:07:15 UTC 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujulz.png)

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-13-alpine AS maven

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src ./src
COPY pom.xml .
# Compile and package the application to an executable JAR
RUN mvn package

# For Java 11,
#FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-ubuntu-jre-11.0.18_10

WORKDIR /opt/app

# Copy the dining-room-spring.jar from the maven stage to the /opt/app directory of the current stage.
# TODO How i can set name of the final .jar?
COPY --from=maven ./app/target/spring.jar .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "spring.jar"]
```

How i can resolve my proble? I just want open this link (https://api.*****.ru/img/c7fb1b0b-41f8...23432.JPG) and see my image. thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot only serves static content from inside the JAR file. From [Serve Static Resources with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources):

> By default, this handler serves static content from any of the
> /static, /public, /resources, and /META-INF/resources directories that
> are on the classpath.

In a Maven project, those directories (`static`, `public`, etc.) should be located in `src/main/resources`, e.g. `src/main/resources/static`.

To use an external folder, set the `spring.web.resources.static-locations` property as shown on the link I provided. In your case I think it would be `spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static,file:.`. That's very dangerous though, as it also makes your application itself downloadable. It's better to use a subdirectory for storing and retrieving files: `spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static,file:files/`.

(Note that I also included `classpath:/static`. That's for serving any static content bundled into your application. You can omit or replace it as necessary.)

---

However, the safest option is probably to add a separate endpoint for retrieving files. That gives you more control over what is and isn't downloadable.

```
    @GetMapping("{file}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@PathVariable("file") String fileName) throws IOException {
        // Check that fileName does not contain any characters that allow escaping the directory
        // Then, open the file and return its contents, content type, content length, etc.
    }
```

Comment: Big thanks for answear! I have thought about this approach @GetMapping("{file}"), but i can't figure out how i can serve my files, that saved localy, with controller? How i must save my files correctly locally? I'am so confused with it

Comment: You now use a `FileOutputStream` to write files. You can easily use a `FileInputStream` to read them again. I do suggest to add a folder so it won't be possible to download your application itself. You also need to make sure that the file is actually located inside that folder and not somewhere else, otherwise attackers can read system files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and finally i solved it with just removing / form the folder name.
"file:/"  it doesnt work.
it should be like this "file:"

```
registry.addResourceHandler(pathPattern).addResourceLocations("file:" + uploadPath + "/");
```